# PDE : $x^2 z_x + y^2 z_y = z(x+y)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Solving the PDE $$x^2 z_x + y^2 z_y = z(x+y)$$

I came across an error in my calculations which I cannot find :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z(x+y)}$$

The first integral curve is given as :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2}\implies z_1 = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}$$

Now, for the second integral curve, I use the following differential subtraction trick to get rid of the $(x+y)$ term :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x-\mathrm{d}y}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z(x+y)}$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(x-y)}{x-y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}$$
$$\implies$$
$$z_2 = \frac{z}{x-y}$$

And thus the general solution is :
$$z_2=F(z_1)\Rightarrow z(x,y)=(x-y)F\bigg(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\bigg)$$
where $F$ is a $C^1$ function of $x$ and $y$.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20*%20d(z(x,y))%2Fdx%20%2B%20y%5E2%20*%20d(z(x,y))%2Fdy%20%3D%20z*(x%2By)) though, states that the solution is $z(x,y)=xyF(1/x-1/y$), which means that I have found the integral curve $z_2$ wrong. I cannot find any fault in my calculations though. The correct integral curve should be :
$$z_2 = \frac{z}{xy}$$
How would one come to this calculation though ?

**I would really appreciate your help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

$$
\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}=C_1 \Rightarrow y-x=C_1 x y
$$

From

$$
\frac{dy-dx}{y-x}=\frac{dz}{z}\Rightarrow y-x = C_2 z
$$

hence

$$
C_2 z = C_1 x y \Rightarrow C_4 = \frac{z}{x y}
$$

Comment: So essentially both solutions are correct ?

Comment: Yes. They are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Some algebra helps too:

$(x-y)F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}\bigg)=xy\left(\dfrac{x-y}{xy}\right)F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}\bigg)=xy\left(\dfrac{1}{y}-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}\bigg)=xyG\left(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}\right)$

with $G\left(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}\right)=-\left(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}\right)F\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{y}\bigg)$

So, they are essentialy the same.

Answer (score 0):

$$dt =\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z(x+y)}$$
is equivalent to 
$$ dt =\frac{zy dx + zx dy - xy dz }{0 },$$

hence the numerator is constant, which only depends on $C_1 = \frac{ 1}{x } - \frac{ 1}{ y}.  $

This implies by integrating each side
$$F(C_1) = zyx + zxy - xyz = zxy,$$
Thus,
$$z = \frac{F(\frac{ 1}{x } - \frac{ 1}{ y}) }{ xy} .$$